# Fabric.js How to resize IText horizontally without stretching the text

Tags: fabricjs

I have this IText object within a parent Group object.

When I select the Group and resize it horizontally (and vertically as well) the IText resizes as well which makes the text Strech and look awfull.

Now what I would like to do is have the IText center itself (keeping its aspect ratio) within the Group.

How can I do that. I tried modifying the Width and Left of the IText when the object is scaling, but that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to make the latest `fabric.Textbox` work exactly like I wanted.

Luckily, I found a way of making the `fabric.IText`center horizontally when the parent `fabric.Group` is resized horizontally and also make the same `fabric.IText` Text grow in size based on the vertical resize. No ugly text stretch.

Here is the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/t44wyday/46/

Answer (score 5):

try use latest fabricjs version ( 1.6.0.rc1 ) and instead of using `fabric.IText` use `fabric.Textbox`.

This new class has the properties you are looking for, the controls normally used for scaling are instead used for resizing the element and the text flows inside it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out fabric.Textbox, but I found a solution with satisfies my requirement. See my anwser.